# how to show different hints in editext programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am using an expandible view where parent is a text view and children are edittext views. I want to show different hints for different edit texts. I tried to do it programmatically but no success at all. Here is my code.

ContactFragment.java

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {
private View mView;
Context mContext;
EditText edittext;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView elv;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getActivity();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_details, container, false);
    ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(mContext, listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    elv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    elv.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    elv.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    elv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    mContext,
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });

return mView;
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Contact Details");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> basic = new ArrayList<String>();
    basic.add(" ");
    basic.add(" ");
    basic.add(" ");
    basic.add(" ");
    basic.add(" ");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), basic); // Header, Child data
}
}
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements TextWatcher{
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
private ArrayList<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
int i=1;
String name,purpose;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}



@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_details_child, null);
    }


    EditText editetext = (EditText) convertView .findViewById(R.id.item);
    while(i<6)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:editetext.setHint("Contact Person");
                break;
            case 2:editetext.setHint("Contact Person Photo");
                break;
            case 3:editetext.setHint("Designation/Job");
                break;
            case 4:editetext.setHint("CEO Name");
                break;
            case 5:editetext.setHint("Company Name");
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    editetext.addTextChangedListener(this);
    editTextList.add(editetext);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_details_parent, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewParent);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                              int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    name=editTextList.get(0).getText().toString();
    purpose=editTextList.get(1).getText().toString();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    System.out.println("Name is"+name);
    System.out.println("purpose is"+purpose);

}
}
```

Comment: First of all, please post only relevant code snippets, not the entire project code. Second, what does "no success at all" mean? EditText has the setHint() method, if it doesn't work for you - then explain what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: ok sure i'll keep that in mind. Yes i tried using that you can see that in my code. using that results in showing no hints at all

Comment: what is the purpose of the while and nested switch statement?

Comment: Pooya i wanted it to loop through all hints and place it at appropriate edittext

Comment: actually you are not doing that, you only assign the "Company Name" to all of them

Comment: But in that case  company name should be displayed there as hint. That is also not the case here.

Comment: you just have 5 edittext in your listview (as a child I mean)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ExpandableListAdapter` class under `getChildView` it looks like you are telling the app to loop through all of the hints and it finishes on "Company Name"

maybe change

```
while(i<6)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:editetext.setHint("Contact Person");
            break;
        case 2:editetext.setHint("Contact Person Photo");
            break;
        case 3:editetext.setHint("Designation/Job");
            break;
        case 4:editetext.setHint("CEO Name");
            break;
        case 5:editetext.setHint("Company Name");
            break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

to

```
switch (childPosition)
{
   case 1:editetext.setHint("Contact Person");
        break;
    case 2:editetext.setHint("Contact Person Photo");
        break;
    case 3:editetext.setHint("Designation/Job");
        break;
    case 4:editetext.setHint("CEO Name");
        break;
    case 5:editetext.setHint("Company Name");
        break;
}
```

Comment: No even that's not working. It is showing no hint at all

Comment: Sorry my bad it was there only but it wasn't visible. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

actual i have better solution why dont u simply use xml code to put hint in your edit text.It will be easy for u and it is not mendetory to code it programmatically.hope u get it

Comment: As i said i am using expandiblelist view and programmatically i am adding 5 edittext so i want 5 different hints to be shown for them